# pdf decoding, what do the bracket and numbers do?

Tags: pdf

my PDF file has deflate encoding, when inflating the string, it outputs something like this:

```
[(Lorem)-21( ipsum)-55( dolor)-14( sit)-55( amet,)-56( consectetur)-8( adipiscing)-14( elit.)-34( Donec)-15( faucibus)-49( lorem)-42( varius2)-56( mauris)-28( porttitor,)-34( et)-28( pellentesque)-1( )]TJ
```

what do the numbers and brackets mean?

it does not seems to be character count, or spacing,

does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an array for showing text (Stuff in brackets denote array objects `[]`), it should be followed by the `TJ` operator. The number is used to translate the text matrix (adjust the positioning of the text). Assuming horizontal text, a negative number moves the next glyph to the right.

From `9.4.3 Text-Showing Operators` (Please see the spec for more details)

> Show one or more text strings, allowing individual glyph positioning.
>   Each element of array shall be either a string or a number. If the
>   element is a string, this operator shall show the string. If it is a
>   number, the operator shall adjust the text position by that amount;
>   that is, it shall translate the text matrix, Tm. The number shall be
>   expressed in thousandths of a unit of text space (see 9.4.4, "Text
>   Space Details"). This amount shall be subtracted from the current
>   horizontal or vertical coordinate, depending on the writing mode. In
>   the default coordinate system, a positive adjustment has the effect of
>   moving the next glyph painted either to the left or down by the given
>   amount.

The parentheses denote string objects:

> String objects shall be written in one of the following two ways:
>
> As a sequence of literal characters enclosed in parentheses ( ) (using
>   LEFT PARENTHESIS (28h) and RIGHT PARENThESIS (29h)); see 7.3.4.2,
>   "Literal Strings."

...

> A literal string shall be written as an arbitrary number of characters
>   enclosed in parentheses. Any characters may appear in a string except
>   unbalanced parentheses (LEFT PARENHESIS (28h) and RIGHT PARENTHESIS
>   (29h)) and the backslash (REVERSE SOLIDUS (5Ch)), which shall be
>   treated specially as described in this sub-clause. Balanced pairs of
>   parentheses within a string require no special treatment.

I suggest getting the [PDF Spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) and reading it to find out more info.

Comment: any hints to what this means in english?

Comment: @JamesYeomans: Sorry, I'm not following you. When you say `what this means in English`, what are you referring to?